# Помогите избавится от копирования в алгоритме

Tags: java, алгоритм

Я принимаю файл через Download Apache Commons FileUpload в результате чего получаю: `List<FileItem> items` из которого мне надо извлечь массив байтов и я делаю это так:

```
public byte[] receive(final List<FileItem> items) {

    final List<Byte> entire = new ArrayList<>();

    for (final FileItem item : items) {

        final byte[] bytes = item.get();

        for (byte b : bytes) {

            entire.add(b);
        }
    }

    final Byte[] bytes = entire.toArray(new Byte[entire.size()]);

    byte[] result = new byte[bytes.length];

    System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, result, 0, result.length);

    return result;
}
```

Но у меня получается куча циклов в которых я все время копирую одни и те же данные, вместо одного файла у меня тут три получается. Какие существуют варианты избавиться от копирования?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`System.arraycopy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy(java.lang.Object,%20int,%20java.lang.Object,%20int,%20int)) выбрасывает исключение когда ему передают массивы разных типов:

> ..., if any of the following is true, an ArrayStoreException is thrown and the destination is not modified:
>   ...
>   The src argument refers to an array with a reference component type and the dest argument refers to an array with a primitive component type.
>
> *... если выполняется одно из следующих условий, выбрасывается ArrayStoreException и массив назначения не изменяется
>
>   ...
>
>   Аргумент `src` — массив ссылочного типа, а аргумент `dest` — массив примитивного типа.*

Я не знаю удобного стандартного способа преобразовать `Byte[]` в `byte[]`. Можно подключить Apache Commons и использовать [`ArrayUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html), что немного сократит код:

```
List<Byte> entire = new ArrayList<>();
for (FileItem item : items) {
    Byte[] itemArray = ArrayUtils.toObject(item.get());
    entire.addAll(Arrays.asList(itemArray));
}
Byte[] bytes = entire.toArray(new Byte[entire.size()]);
return ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(bytes);
```

Чтобы избежать многократного создания массивов можно создать большой массив для результата и копировать все остальные в него, например, так:

```
//собираем массивы
List<byte[]> contents = new ArrayList<>();
for (FileItem item : items) {
    contents.add(item.get());
}
//считаем суммарную длину
int totalLength = 0;
for (byte[] content : contents) {
    totalLength += content.length;
}
//собираем в один массив
byte[] entire = new byte[totalLength];
int offset = 0;
for (byte[] content : contents) {
    System.arraycopy(content, 0, entire, offset, content.length);
    offset += content.length;
}
return entire;
```

Метод можно сразу разбить на три:

```
public static byte[] receive(final List<FileItem> items) {
    List<byte[]> contents = getContents(items);
    int totalLength = calculateTotalLength(contents);
    return mergeAll(contents, totalLength);
}
```

или на два:

```
public static byte[] receive(final List<FileItem> items) {
    return mergeAll(getContents(items));
}
```